# Is it safe to install updated Intel drivers from the x-swat PPA?

Tags: intel-graphics, ppa

Is it safe to install updated Intel drivers for Ubuntu 11.10 from the following PPAs?

```
ppa:glasen/intel-driver
ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Here's my system spec.

- Sony Vaio S-series VPCSE190X
- Intel Core i7-2640M processor (2.80GHz / 3.50GHz with Turbo Boost)
- AMD Radeon HD 6630M (1GB) hybrid graphics with Intel HD Graphics 3000

Please share your experiences.

Comment: I have not had any issues with the Intel Drivers and Gnome Shell however i had issues with the AMD card on another computer, this leads me to think that you're seeing this  because of the AMD card.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with crashes says if it is not broken dont try to fix it. Drivers from repos work fine for me but I have read many who have broke their installation due to third party drivers. So unless current drivers don't  work for you don't try it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I'm asking because I have a few issues with gnome-shell and the current intel drivers v2.15.

Comment: Have you tried to resolve them without resorting to that option?