# How to upgrade intel graphics package?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics

I have a Intel i7 laptop that does not show any resolution higher than 1280 x 1024. A little bit of research pointed me to a bug and subsequently to a fix. I have 11.10 currently installed. I want to upgrade the driver so that the graphics start working again.

How can I do this ?

- [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/912397)
- [Release with fix](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2012.02.html)

Comment: It doesn't look like the second link has anything related to your issues. What there is the fix, and how do you know?

Comment: I looked at the validation hardware for the release which mentions a suite of intel hardware including mine. So, I assumed it is worth a try. A vague look at the "Major known issues" section suggested that it dealt with Sandy Bridge display issues. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update your graphics drivers, open a terminal console and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After restarting the computer, your system should be running the current graphics drivers. I hope this helps

- [Is it safe to install updated Intel drivers from the x-swat PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92393/is-it-safe-to-install-updated-intel-drivers-from-the-x-swat-ppa)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try the "The Intel® Graphics Installer for Linux*" : it allows you to easily install the latest graphics and video drivers for your Intel graphics hardware. This allows you to stay current with the latest enhancements, optimizations, and fixes to the Intel® Graphics Stack to ensure the best user experience with your Intel® graphics hardware. The Intel® Graphics Installer for Linux* is available for the latest versions of Ubuntu* and Fedora*."

See https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads