# How do I install working drivers for an Intel 4500MHD? (12.04 LTS)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade intel graphics package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124640/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-package)

I was running Ubuntu 11.10 before, today I decided to do a fresh install of 12.04 because when I tried the beta, I had graphics issues. Being quite fresh to Ubuntu (although I deployed Server to many machines, Im familiar with the CLI not the GUI). In any case, after tinkering around and configuring 11.10 to my liking, I found the "Details" button in "System Settings", in 11.10 under "Graphics", it listed my chipset fine, and these issues did not exist, in the 12 Beta and Final Release, it says graphics are unknown. I have a Dell Latitude E5500 with 4500MHD Graphics. Can anyone please advise on how to get proper video drivers? Big thanks.

Tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Rebooted, the video driver now display in the "Details" window, but the same screen artifacts persist. For example, when I enter each letter of my password, and when I hit enter on the login screen, the screen flashes and flickers and stuff. When I'm on the "Details" and I change tabs, a bottom portion of the desktop flickers. This is really, really annoying.

Edit: If this is of any help, if I use Ubuntu 2D, the problem disappears. Something to do with OpenGL drivers?

Comment: This is bad. I'm at a standstill. I want to use 12.04 but if no one helps me resolve this issue I'll have to reinstall 11.10 so I'm stuck with a fresh install, none of my apps and I'm withholding from any configuration changes. Please help oh Might Ubuntu Gods! (Goes to sacrifice a lamb)

Comment: You should probably file a bug report. Intel has crappy graphical hardware and even crappier Linux driver support. No big secret here. Meanwhile, just use Unity2d.

Comment: You have gone for more than a month with over 1,000 views but no answers. I suggest you [*collect the info*](http://askubuntu.com/q/14008/52923) needed so you can [*create a bug report on launchpad*](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/52923) that someone could investigate. You might also consider editing your question so that its focus is on how to isolate and report your problem so you can file a better bug report. (The closer you can get to the root cause of your problem, the more likely it is that someone will create and release a fix for it.)

Comment: perhaps updating the intel graphics driver & xserver works for you too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124640/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-package/125197#125197

Comment: Related issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/210448/does-the-kernel-also-need-to-be-updated-if-i-update-the-intel-drivers