# 12.04 does not work with Intel GM 45

Tags: 12.04, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install working drivers for an Intel 4500MHD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128517/how-do-i-install-working-drivers-for-an-intel-4500mhd)

Someone answer this please:
[How do I install working drivers for an Intel 4500MHD? (12.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/q/128517/67828)

A ton of us all over the Internet have this problem and nobody is giving any answers at all. Is it just a known bug? Does 12.04 just not work with this extremely common graphics chip? What is the answer?