# Unable to install driver for Nvidia GT540M on 10.04

Tags: 10.04, nvidia

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 10.04 on my Dell XPS15 L502x notebook, but I can't find a solution about how to install the Nvidia driver.

Could someone help me please ?

[Spec](http://www.pcworld.com/product/926445/dell_xps_15_l502x.html?p=specs)

```
Graphics
Graphics Type -------------------------------- Switchable
Integrated Graphics Chipset ------------------ Intel
Integrated Graphics Chipset Model Number ----- HD Core i5
Discreet Graphics Chipset -------------------- Nvidia GeForce
Discreet Graphics Chipset Model Number ------- GT 525M
Graphics Memory ------------------------------ 1024 MB
```

Comment: Seems to me that your graphics card is too new for Ubuntu 10.04. An xserver update might solve your problem, perhaps this procedure helps (ignore the topic): http://askubuntu.com/questions/124640/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-package-to-the-12-02-release/125197#125197

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/product/926445/dell_xps_15_l502x.html

Answer (score 0):

The driver is too old, but the x-updates ppa provides a current driver for 10.04. However I would recommend installing 12.04 for new installs.