# Ubuntu 12.04 fails to find Intel HD Graphics 3000

Tags: 12.04, graphics, intel, jockey

On my Windows 7 installation an Intel HD Graphics 3000 card/driver shows. However in Ubuntu 12.04, System → Administration → Hardware Drivers shows no proprietary drivers available for the system.

I have tried running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Which results in the graphics driver incorrectly identifying itself as Sandy Bridge *Mobile*.

Running the following results in no change

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Does anybody have any information on this behavior?

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124640/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-package/125197#125197

Comment: All Intel's own graphics cards use the same open source driver, there exists no closed source driver, so none will be shown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandy Bridge was the code name for the 2nd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors (i3, i5, i7)

It is being identified correctly if you have a laptop, maybe not if it's a desktop but I doubt it will matter.

Comment: This is probably closest to being right. It is indeed a laptop, but I was thrown off because the processor reports separately as i5, I thought the graphics should report separately as Intel HD 3000.

Comment: Yea it's rather confusing, I only know this as mine is a Sandy Bridge Desktop.  Not sure why it identifies as it does.  I can tell you from experience that Sandy Bridge will run some of the better games but to get it to work you need to install the s3tc libraries for mesa.  They will allow the texture compression needed. They are called       libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0   you can find them via Software Center, Synaptic, or command line.

Comment: Intel HD 3000 = Sandy Bridge Mobile is correct. The Intel HD 3000 is integrated in the CPU.